# Mongo DB find() function not working node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

```
const User = require('./models/user')

module.exports = new class Users {
    async get(token) {
        return await User.find({"activeToken": token}).exec();
    }
}
```

My find function always returns "Couldn't find what you were looking for", I have tried users.activateToken, User.activateToken and just activateToken and it still doesn't work.

```
{
    "_id": "text",
    "activeToken": "abcdefg",
    "activated": "false",
    "email": "email",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The error thrown is just "null"

Function Im trying to run it with:

```
 bot.on('message',  async (message) => {
     
     
    const user =  await users.get(message.content);
    if (message.content == user.activeToken && !user.activated && message.channel.type == 'dm') {
        user.discord_id = message.member.id;
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.member_role);
        console.log("Test");
        if(role){
            try {
                console.log("You Won");
                message.member.roles.add(role);
                message.author.send(replyText);
                user.activated = true;
                user.activeToken = "";
                
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log("Error Occured");
            }
            
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log(user);
    }


    
})
```

This line of code

```
console.log(user);
```

returns (0) []
with "user.activeToken"

but returns (1) [model]
with just regular "activeToken"

User Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;





//user schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    discord_id: String,
    email: String,
    activeToken: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    activated: {
        type: String,
        default: false
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always returns that message because that's what you're logging when there is no error!

```
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Couldn't find what you were looking for");
```

in case of an error you're re-throwing it, so the console.log will not be executed.

I assume you're using `mongoose`.

the function should be written like so

```
async get(token) {
    return await User.findOne({"activeToken": token}).exec()
}
```

And you should use `findOne` to get a single object.

refer to this for full description:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#built-in-promises

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, that clarified a lot; however Its still not working even with the updated code. (edited question)

Comment: can you share your User's schema

Comment: Ive just updated my question with all the relevant code

Comment: Im actually using mongodb

Comment: ok you're using mongodb, but the mongoose package
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');`